# BIRT reporting printing area

Tags: birt

I'm working in BIRT reports. I'm facing some issues with when importing the report to pdf format.
this is the issue I'm facing

Report is generated successfully in BIRT viewer. But when it exports to the pdf report alignment will change.It prints only left to right around 80% from the original report.I think issue with print area.In designer it report width is more than the print with.I try to reduce it but I couldn't reduce the width of the table.I think reason is the table i'm using in the report. Table has 8 columns so I couldn't reduce the width of columns. column has minimum width, I can't reduce more than than.
So what can I do to this issue ?
Anyone knows the solution to this issue ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could try making the font in your table one of the relative sizes (small, medium, large) rather than a hard 10 pts, 12 pts, etc. And then make the column width a percentage instead of a definite pixel number. E.g. column 1: 15%, column 2: 10%, column 3: 5%, column 4: 20%, column 5: 20%, column 6: 30% - or however it best fits the contents.

There isn't much you can do beyond that because you are rendering it onto a PDF document that is going to be the exact size of your master page, however you have that defined (letter size, legal, etc). If you haven't changed the orientation of your master page from portrait to landscape (on the master page tab), you could try that if it is workable for you.

Comment: Thank you for valuable comment , I have done those things except re sizing the font , I'll try to do that, I tried with setting master page as letter , A4 , etc but didn't work .I'll try with font size

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the sizes, padding, margin etc in mm (or inches) works well. This also ensures exact measurements. The background images are exceptions, because they're pixel-based.

Comment: Cannot imagine why someone down-voted this. It's just the correct answer. The PDF emitter is the most-precise emitter. Just keep in mind that with PDF, your page has a fixed size, e.g. US letter or A4. Keep in mind the master-page margins. *Always* use fixed sizes for fonts (eg. 10pt) as well as for all measures like table width, column width etc. Keep in mind that you can also explicitly delete the width property for tables/grid and columns. This means: Use all the available width for table for tables/grids; ...

Comment: For columns it means: Compute w := container's (e.g. page's) available width - sum(column.width for column in columns width width specified).   n := count(columns with width not specified). For each column with width not specified, set width := w/n